# Access root of drive with a Unix-like shell

Tags: cygwin, directory-structure

I'm using Cygwin to compile a library. The library is not stored within the same directory as Cygwin. I need to navigate to this directory in order to compile the library. The Cygwin shell only allows me to go back as far as the Cygwin root directory using **cd ..** .

The command **su** returns the following:

```
su: user root does not exist
```

How do I navigate my hard drive using Cygwin if the **su** command doesn't work?

Comment: Why would `su` navigate your hard drive in the first place? (you're probably looking for `/cygdrive/`)

Comment: I was under the impression that the 'su' command would 'unlock' access to directories outside of the Cygwin folder. As you can tell, I'm (very) new to Unix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Wooble, the solution is to use the command `/cygdrive/` , followed by the drive letter. So, to access the root of the C: drive, type `cd /cygdrive/c`.